# Show specific sections in Setup

Tags: profile, user-management

Is there a known way to restrict access to some users related to specific areas of setup? For example, i want user A to see only users and profiles, but not to be able to see objects, fields, custom settings etc. I want user B to be able to see objects, fields etc, but not users. How could this be applied ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow particular profile user's to see all the users in the org, profile requires [View and Manage Users](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_users.htm&type=5) permission which requires **View Setup and Configuration** permission on the profile level. Once you given the **view setup and configuration** to the profile, it will allow the profile to do many other things to do which you do not want.

Read all the permission that you can control here:- [User Profile permission descriptions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332385&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)